# Using cup product to compute a map $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^n;\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^*(\mathbb{C}P^n;\mathbb{Z}) $

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is exercise 3.2.6 in Hatcher's book. It says use cup products to compute the map $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^n;\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^*(\mathbb{C}P^n;\mathbb{Z}) $ induced by the map $\mathbb{C}P^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$ that is a quotient of the map $\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ where $(z_0,...,z_n) \mapsto (z_0^d,...z_n^d)$. He also says to do the case $n=1$ first.

Note that we are looking at the induced map of $F:\mathbb{C}P^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$; $F[v]=[v^d]$.

Since $\mathbb{C}P^n;\mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(\alpha^{n+1})$ where $\alpha$ is a generator of $H^{2}(\mathbb{C}P^n;\mathbb{Z})$, it suffices to determine $F^*(\alpha)$.

For the case $n=1$, we have $\mathbb{C}P^1 \simeq S^2$ hence the induced map on homology $F_*:H_2(\mathbb{C}P^1) \rightarrow H_2(\mathbb{C}P^1)$ is multiplication by some integer $m$, i.e. $F_*(\beta)=m\beta$, which is the degree of $F$.

I want to show that $m=d$ (what else could the degree possibly be?), from which I did exercise 3.1.9 earlier which says $F^*(\alpha)=d\alpha$ as well.

> The standard way to compute degrees is to use local degrees, where the degree of $F$ is the sum of its local degrees. I am confused on how to apply this since we don't *literally* have a map from $S^2 \rightarrow S^2$ but instead a map of spaces that are homeomorphic to $S^2$.

Comment: Can you not just choose a homeomorphism $S^2\cong \mathbb{C}P^1$ and compose $S^2\cong \mathbb{C}P^1\xrightarrow{F} \mathbb{C}P^1\cong S^2$?

Comment: When you restrict $F$ to $S^2$ you should get a map such that $z\mapsto z^d$ (with $z\in \mathbf C\cup\{\infty\}$). It's then not difficult to see that such a map induces a map of degree $d$.

Comment: @Tyrone Yes and the degree of that composition will be the degree, but not sure how to compute that.